# Autocompletion not working in VS Code C/C++ project

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I have a very large C/C++ project in VS Code 1.67.2. I have been using the Instellisense plugin and it's always worked properly: I was able to navigate the code, use suggestion/autocompletion and so on.

Now it seems not to work properly: in case of function I can still navigate properly (by `CRL+left mouse click`) but not in the case of variables: for example, in a body function if I click on a input parameter name it does not move the cursor to the function signature where that variable is defined. Furthermore, autocomplete is not working at all and that's quite annoying.

I have already tried to reset the Intellisense Database as suggested in other posts but it didn't help.

Any help, particularly for the autocompletion/suggestion?

Comment: i'm too having the same exact issue, have you found a solution?